# How to calculate cryptographic checksum using 3DES-outer-CBC mode

Tags: algorithm, des

I want to calculate a cryptographic checksum using 3DES in outer CBC mode. As I know (and tried Googling also ) 3DES is an encryption algorithm, I'm not getting getting any information about how it can be used to calculate a checksum. Or may be I am missing some link here. Please correct me if I am wrong.
I need this to form over-the-air SMS.

Comment: So you want to do [CBC-MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBC-MAC) or something differently?

Answer (score 1):

3DES in outer CBC mode [DES-EDE3-CBC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2451) (Page 6; here details in the application of ipsec/esp). [Here's](http://blog.senthadev.com/2013/04/02/Ciphering-with-TripleDES-in-outer-CBC-mode-using-2-keys/) a code snippet for 3DES in outer CBC mode in a related application.

What you'll most likely have to do is to encrypt a message `m` using DES-EDE3-CBC and then throw away all but the last block of ciphertext (CBC-MAC). The `iv` is typically fixed at `0`.